# Generate Linus Sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory, subsequence

## Definition

From the description on OEIS [A006345](https://oeis.org/A006345):

> To find `a(n)`, consider either a `1` or a `2`. For each, find the longest repeated suffix, that is, for each of `a(n)=1,2`, find the longest sequence `s` with the property that the sequence `a(1),...,a(n)` ends with `ss`. Use the digit that results in the shorter such suffix. `a(1) = 1`.

## Worked-out Example

`a(1)=1`.

If `a(2)=1`, we will have the sequence `1 1` where the longest doubled substring from the end is `1`. If `a(2)=2` instead, then it would be the empty substring. Therefore `a(2)=2`.

When `n=6`, we choose between `1 2 1 1 2 1` and `1 2 1 1 2 2`. In the first choice, `1 2 1` is doubled consecutively from the end. In the second choice, it is `2` instead. Therefore, `a(6)=2`.

When `n=9`, we choose between `1 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 1`  and `1 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2`. In the first choice, the longest doubled consecutive substring is `2 1`, while in the second choice `1 2 2` is doubled consecutively at the end. Therefore `a(9)=1`.

## Task

Given `n`, return `a(n)`.

## Specs

- `n` will be positive.
- You can use 0-indexed instead of 1-indexed. In that case, please state so in your answer. Also, in that case, `n` can be `0` also.

## Testcases

The testcases are 1-indexed. However, you can use 0-indexed.

```
n  a(n)
1  1
2  2
3  1
4  1
5  2
6  2
7  1
8  2
9  1
10 1
11 2
12 1
13 2
14 2
15 1
16 1
17 2
18 1
19 1
20 1
```

## References

- [WolframMathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinusSequence.html)
- Obligatory [OEIS A006345](https://oeis.org/A006345)

Comment: In the test case of `n=9`, the first choice `1 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 1` has the doubled substring `2 1` at the end.

Comment: Note that the linked OEIS page has a golfed Perl solution of ~43 bytes.

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, <s>146</s> <s>140</s> <s>137</s> <s>133</s> 118 bytes

```
s!l|take l s==take l(drop l s)=l|1<2=s!(l-1)
g[w,x]|w<x=1|1<2=2
a 1=1
a n=g$(\s x->(x:s)!n)(a<$>[n-1,n-2..1])<$>[1,2]
```

Comment: Do you really need `(\x->(\s->...`? Otherwise you could write `(\x s->...`.

Comment: That helps to save a few

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Instead of using the sane upper bound `div ...`, you can use the shorter `n`. The extra comparisons will all return false and not change the result.

Comment: ooh nice, I guess I assumed take would crash if given too large a value

Answer (score 6):

### Python, 137 bytes

```
def a(n,s=[0],r=lambda l:max([0]+filter(lambda i:l[-i:]==l[-i*2:-i],range(len(l))))):
 for _ in[0]*n:s+=[r(s+[0])>r(s+[1])]
 return-~s[n]
```

This solution is using 0-based indexing.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>25</s> <s>24</s> <s>22</s> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

**2 bytes thanks to Dennis.**

```
2;€µḣJf;`€$ṪLµÞḢ
Ç¡Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MjvigqzCteG4o0rFk3MyRSTDkGbhuapMwrXDnuG4ogrDh8Kh4bii&input=MjA)

A port of my [answer in Pyth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87356/48934).

```
Ç¡Ḣ   Main chain

 ¡    Repeat for (input) times:
Ç         the helper chain
  Ḣ   Then take the first element



2;€µḣJf;`€$ṪLµÞḢ  Helper chain, argument: z

2;€               append z to 1 and 2, creating two possibilities
   µ         µÞ   sort the possibilities by the following:
    ḣJ                generate all prefixes from shortest to longest
       ;`€            append the prefixes to themselves
      f   $           intersect with the original set of prefixes
           Ṫ          take the last prefix in the intersection
            L         find its length
                 Ḣ   take the first (minimum)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 84 bytes

```
a@n_:=a@n=First@MinimalBy[{1,2},Array[a,n-1]~Append~#/.{___,b___,b___}:>Length@{b}&]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>30</s> <s>29</s> <s>28</s> <s>27</s> 24 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
;€¬;\€Z;/f;`€$ṪḢ;
1Ç¡o2Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=O-KCrMKsO1zigqxaOy9mO2Digqwk4bmq4biiOwoxw4fCoW8y4bii&input=&args=MTk) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=O-KCrMKsO1zigqxaOy9mO2Digqwk4bmq4biiOwoxw4figbjCoW8y4biiCjIw4bi2xbzDh-KCrCRH&input=).

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 34 bytes

```
vXKi:"2:"K@h'(.+)\1$'XXgn]>QhXK]0)
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dlhLaToiMjoiS0BoJyguKylcMSQnWFhnbl0-UWhYS10wKQ&input=MTc) or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YCAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAlIGRvLi4ud2hpbGUgbG9vcAp2WEtpOiIyOiJLQGgnKC4rKVwxJCdYWGduXT5RaFhLXTApICAgICUgYWN0dWFsIGNvZGUKRCAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAlIGRpc3BsYXkgcmVzdWx0ClQgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgJSBsb29wIGNvbmRpdGlvbjogaW5maW5pdGUgbG9vcA&input=MQoyCjMKNAo1CjYKNwo4CjkKMTAKMTEKMTIKMTMKMTQKMTUKMTYKMTcKMTgKMTkKMjA).

#### Explanation

```
v             % Concatenate stack vertically: produces empty array
XK            % Copy to clipboard K. This clipboard holds the current sequence
i:            % Take input n. Generate vector [1 2 ... n]
"             % For each k in [1 2 ... n]
  2:          %   Push [1 2]. These are the possible digits for extending the sequence
  "           %     For each j in [1 2]
    K         %       Push contents of clipboard K (current sequence)
    @         %       Push j (1 or 2)
    h         %       Concatenate horizontally: gives a possible extension of sequence
    '(.+)\1$' %       String to be used as regex pattern: maximal-length repeated suffix
    XX        %       Regex match
    gn        %       Convert to vector and push its length: gives length of match
  ]           %    End. We now have the suffix lengths of the two possible extensions
  >           %    Push 1 if extension with "1" has longer suffix than with "2"; else 0 
  Q           %    Add 1: gives 2 if extension with "1" produced a longer suffix, or 1
              %    otherwise. This is the digit to be appended to the sequence
  h           %    Concatenate horizontally
  XK          %    Update clipboard with extended sequence, for the next iteration
]             % End
0)            % Get last entry (1-based modular indexing). Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 94 bytes

```python
import re
s='1'
exec"s+=`3-int(re.search(r'(.*)(.)\\1$',s).groups()[1])`;"*input()
print s[-1]
```

Uses 0-based indexing. Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/c26gpy).

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>46</s> 29 bytes

Took some inspiration from @Leaky Nun's excellent Pyth answer. Tried to see if there was a shorter way using strings. Still 3 bytes short!

```
huh.melM+kf!x>blTT._bm+dGS2Qk
```

You can try it out [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=huh.melM%2Bkf%21x%3EblTT._bm%2BdGS2Qk&input=1&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12%0A13%0A14%0A15%0A16%0A17%0A18%0A19%0A20&debug=0).

Comment: Using red`u`ce instead of explicit for-loop [saves you 4 bytes](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=heu%2BGehS.e%2CeS.e%26qZ%3AbhYh%2BYlZhY._bkm_%2BGdU2QY&input=1+%0A2+%0A3+%0A4+%0A5+%0A6+%0A7+%0A8+%0A9+%0A10%0A11%0A12%0A13%0A14%0A15%0A16%0A17%0A18%0A19%0A20&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 26 bytes

```
huh.mleq#.<T/lT2._b+RGS2QY
```

[Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=huh.mleq%23.%3CT%2FlT2._b%2BRGS2QY&input=1+%0A2+%0A3+%0A4+%0A5+%0A6+%0A7+%0A8+%0A9+%0A10%0A11%0A12%0A13%0A14%0A15%0A16%0A17%0A18%0A19%0A20&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12%0A13%0A14%0A15%0A16%0A17%0A18%0A19%0A20&debug=0)

#### Explanation

When `n = 6`, we choose between `1 2 1 1 2 1` and `1 2 1 1 2 2`.

We generate these two possibilities, and then look at their suffixes.

For the first one, the suffixes are: `1`, `2 1`, `1 2 1`, `1 1 2 1`, `2 1 1 2 1`, `1 2 1 1 2 1`.

We filter for doubled suffixes by checking if they are the same after rotating them for their length divided by 2 (it turns out that this check is not perfect, because it confirms `1` and `2` also).

We take the last doubled suffix and then take its length.

We then choose the possibility that corresponds to a minimum length generated above.

Then we proceed to the next value of `n`.

For the purpose of this program, it was golfier to generate the reversed array instead.

```
huh.mleq#.<T/lT2._b+RGS2QY
 u                      QY   repeat Q (input) times,
                             start with Y (empty array),
                             storing the temporary result in G:
                   +RGS2         prepend 1 and 2 to G,
                                 creating two possibilities
   .m             b              find the one that
                                 makes the following minimal:
                ._                   generate all prefixes
       q#                            filter for prefixes as T
                                     that equals:
         .<T/lT2                         T left-rotated
                                         by its length halved
      e                              take the last one
     l                               generate its length
  h                              take the first minimal one
h                                take the first one from the generated
                                 array and implicitly print it out
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 40 bytes

```perl
$a.=/(.*)(.)\1$/^$2for($a)x$_;$_=$a%5+1
```

The code is **39 bytes** long and requires the `-p` switch (**+1** byte).

The loop is inspired by the Perl solution on the relevant [OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A006345), although I did come up independently with the regular expression.

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Yzck9i).

Comment: You have outgolfed OEIS, specifically, Ton Hospel/Phil Carmody...

Comment: Not really comparable since the OEIS script takes no input and prints the whole sequence.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>51</s> 42 bytes

**9 bytes thanks to Martin Ender.**

```
.+
$*x
+`((.*)(^|2|(?<3>1))\2)x
$1$#3
!`.$
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LisKJCp4CitgKCguKikoXnwyfCg_PDM-MSkpXDIpeAokMSQjMwohYC4k&input=MjA)

A port of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87352/48934).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 84

Index base 0

```js
n=>eval("s='1';for(r=d=>(s+d).match(/(.*)\\1$/)[0].length;n--;s+=c)c=r(1)>r(2)?2:1")
```

**Less golfed**

```js
n=>{
  r = d => (s+d).match(/(.*)\1$/)[0].length;
  c = '1';
  for(s = c; n--; s += c)
    c = r(1) > r(2) ? 2 : 1;
  return c;
}
```

**Test**

```js
F=
n=>eval("s='1';for(r=d=>(s+d).match(/(.*)\\1$/)[0].length;n--;s+=c)c=r(1)>r(2)?2:1")

for(n=0;n<20;n++)console.log(n,F(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 20 bytes

```
!¡λ◄(L←SnmDṫ:⁰)ḣ2);1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9odXNr//8hwqHOu@KXhChM4oaQU25tROG5qzrigbAp4bijMik7Mf///zIw) or [Verify first 20 values](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9odXNr///ihpHCoc674peEKEzihpBTbm1E4bmrOuKBsCnhuKMyKTsx////MjA)

Same algorithm as Leaky Nun's answers.